# How to completely disconnect the GATT connection in the HarmonyOS system

Tags: android

When I use gatt.disconnect method to disconnect a ble in the HarmonyOS system, I find that the device is still connected (here I use the BluetoothManager.getConnectionState method to verify this situation, disconnect is not working but gatt is closed). How can I make the device completely disconnected? Because I want to disconnect the GATT connection and establish a new Bluetooth socket connection for other operations. But if Gatt fails to disconnect, it will result in my subsequent socket read/write disconnections

And this issue only occurs on the HarmonyOS system, I can still disconnect the Gatt connection normally when using the same operation on other Android systems. Do you have any ideas for me to handle this issue?